# How to add one column into second column of sql in sublime text 3 using php?

Tags: php, xampp

```
UPDATE `fee` SET `remaining` = (`fees` + `remaining`)
```

This query is working very well in localhost but not working in sublime text 3
I want to run this query in sublime text 3 using php"

```
$data = array('remaining' => ('fees' + 'remaining' ), );
$con = array('id' => 1, );   
$ins1=$fun->edit_data('fee',$data,$con);
   if ($ins1) {
    echo "Update Successfully";
   } else {
    echo "Some Error";
   }
```

output should be `fees+remaining` but the actual output is `0`.

Comment: query doesn't depend on sublime or any editor.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
$data = array('remaining' => ('fees' + 'remaining' ), );
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you want mathematical add 2 strings. Both strings are converted to the number `0`. So the data line is reduced to:

```
$data = array('remaining' => 0 );
```

I think you want something like:

```
$data = array( 'remaining' => 'fees + remaining' );
```